# Zipping a HTTP Response? Possible?

Tags: java, http, zip

Having an issue where certain page's contents are abnormally huge. In the 5 to 10 megs range.

This is rendered using Velocity and Java on the server side. It's obviously possible to compress/zip this response but what's a reasonable way to handle the unzipping on the browser/client side?

Comment: Would just like to point out that if the response is huge because it's full of jpegs and gifs, they're already compressed.  Zipping won't help.  I'm not sure PDFs can be zipped successfully, either.

Comment: I think unencrypted pdfs are pretty compressible (unless they are full of compressed images, of course)

Comment: If your response is really that big, transporting it across the network will be the least of your problems. It should be broken up into smaller chunks as most browsers will struggle to render such enormous files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's built-in to most modern browsers. As long as the response is some kind of text or something easily compressible then your request/response just have to have to correct headers.

**Request**

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

**Response**

Content-Encoding: gzip

If the Accept-Encoding header of the request doesn't include gzip you shouldn't zip it obviously because the client/browser can't handle it.

In general you should gzip any text content as long as it makes sense to do so. If the resource is 500 bytes instead of 500kbytes it might not make sense for performance reasons.
Some examples are html, xml, json, javascript and you can configure your server, which types of files to compress and what the size limit should be.

Enabling Gzip

- [Tomcat](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/11/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat.html)
- [IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Glassfish](http://www.vikasing.com/2010/01/enable-gzip-compression-on-glassfish-v3.html)

Comment: So would this transmit a huge compressed web page over the innertubes is such a way that the browser would automatically decompress and display the web page, or would the browser display a pop-up that asked the user to either open the zip file or save it to disk?

Comment: @Tony Ennis This would transmit whatever resource the client has requested and the browser would automatically decompress the resource. Keep in mind that viewing a single web page usually results in multiple requests to the server. Request for the html page, and requests for each image, etc.

Comment: The requests for the images are showing up separately so this is inline JS and <html> only. The output is obviously very inefficient/large.

Comment: @bobber205 Might want to consider putting the JS into separate files then instead of inline to take advantage of gzipping + simultaneous requests.

Comment: Our first idea for optimizing this monster. Not super easy because alot of the functions are made up of custom names with velocity variables. :(